# Is there a named operation for the sum of a vector's elements?

Tags: summation, vectors, arithmetic, binary-operations

If I have a vector $<a,b>$ is there a name or specific notation for adding the elements to create a scalar $c$, such that $c=a+b$?

For reference, I want to use this to rationalize a notion I have. With a function $f: R^{2}→R$ such that, given a vector $q=<x,y>$,  $f(q)=x+y$, I want to say that the operation of summing the elements of a vector is distributive over vector addition.

I.e.
$f(<x,y>+<v,u>)=f(<x,y>)+f(<v,u>)$ because (insert name of operation here) is distributive over vector addition.

Comment: It is just the dot product with $(1,1)$. Distributivity just follows.

Comment: When $a$ and $b$ are both nonnegative, this is the $L^1$ norm, $|\langle a, b \rangle|_1 = |a| + |b|$. But if you want to not take the absolute value in the case of vectors with negative coordinates, then I don't think this operation has a special name.